# Identify an option from a select using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I want to a client, choose a specific option, from a `<select>`, and that option has to do one thing:

**Remove a class attribute "disabled", from `<div id="addoptions" class="disabled">`.**

The  value I want to get, when selected is: `<option value="mobile">`

I tried other posts, i saw some options and nothing worked for me.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ujgx4st3/5/

HTML

```
   <select id="service">

                        <option selected="selected">Choose one of the options</option>

                        <optgroup label=""></optgroup>

                        <optgroup label="Web Development">
                            <option value="manage">Website Management</option>
                            <option value="update">Update to Responsive</option>
                            <option value="coding">Page Coding</option>
                            <option value="software">Software Programming</option>
                            <option value="mobile">Mobile Application</option>
                        </optgroup>

    </select></br></br>


    <div id="appoptions" class="col-md-3 disabled">

                        <div style="margin: 25px 0;">
                            <label><b>Application options</b> <small>(mobile)</small></label></br></br>

<input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="android" disabled>Android</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="apple" disabled>Apple</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="windows" disabled>Windows Phone</label></br>
<input type="checkbox" name="platform" value="webapp" disabled>Web application</br>
                        </div>
                    </div>


<div id="appoptions" class="col-md-3 disabled">

   <div style="margin: 25px 0">
        <label><b>Type of application</b></label></br></br>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="mobile" value="pay" disabled>Include payments options</br>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="mobile" value="users" disabled>Add registration</br>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="mobile" value="connect" disabled>Connected to Social Media</br>

<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="mobile" value="settings" disabled>Add app options</br>

     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What javascript have you tried till now ? I couldn't find any in your jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in jQuery:

```
$("#service").change(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == "manage")
        $("#appoptions").removeClass("disabled");
});
```

For example, this will remove the disabled class on `#appoptions` when the option with the `"manage"` is selected. Which would be the one with the text `"Website Management"`. Of course you could use `"mobile"` other than `"manage"` if you wish to.

[**Here is an example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ujgx4st3/6/)

Comment: Awesome! I adapted to "mobile" (since is the option im looking for), removed the id "appoptions" and changed to class "options".

This way, both div, remove the "disabled" class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#service").change(function(){

    $("#appoptions").removeClass("disabled");


})
```